# How to resolve "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm converting a text field into date time and inserting into db. However, when the text field is null, it throws an exception that

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

This is what I did:

```
    nvpt4Entities db = new nvpt4Entities();

    ClassInfo order = new ClassInfo
    {
        ClassID = classID.Text,
        ClassName = className.SelectedItem.Text,
        ClassTime = classTime1.Text,
        ClassDate = DateTime.ParseExact(classDate1.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null),
        ClassDay = classDay.SelectedValue,
        ClassMonth = classMonth.SelectedValue,
        ClassLocation = classLocation.SelectedItem.Text,
        ClassNotes= classNotes.Text,
        ClassInstructor = classInstructor.SelectedValue,
        ClassInstructor1 = classInstructor2.SelectedValue,
        ClassInstructor2 = classInstructor3.SelectedValue,
        MultiDate2 = DateTime.ParseExact(multidate2.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null),
        MultiDate3 = DateTime.ParseExact(multidate3.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null),
        MultiDate4 = DateTime.ParseExact(multidate4.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null),
        MultiDate5 = DateTime.ParseExact(multidate5.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null),
        ClassStrength =  Convert.ToInt16(classStrength.Text),
        ClassProvider = classProvider.SelectedItem.Text,
        LocationID = Convert.ToInt16(classLocation.SelectedValue),
        ClassCID = Convert.ToInt16(className.SelectedValue),
        ProviderID = Convert.ToInt16(classProvider.SelectedValue)

    };
```

So, I want to know how to handle null strings to be converted to datetime while inserting into db

Comment: What do you want the null strings to be converted to?  Are these nullable `DateTime` columns?

Comment: no they are not nullable datetime columns

Comment: So what should a null string be converted to, then?

Comment: Then you can't shove a null into that column

Comment: Well that is a design question, why is the column currently not null?

Comment: yeah.... I got that but can u let me know the way i could create nullable datetime in sql server.. I did the field as datetime and allowed nulls.... but could not find datetime?

Answer (score 3):

This has *nothing* to do with the database. Pay attention to the error message and where the exception originates. The only thing of relevance is where the error comes from:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(__, "MM/dd/yyyy", null)
```

Replace this with an appropriate method call that handles the "empty/invalid string" case, however is appropriate, *or* use validation to ensure this step is never reached; `DateTime?` should be used for nullable columns, a sentinel can be used otherwise. (See Mark Byers' answer for what the contents of said method may look like.)

Happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

If your fields are nullable DateTimes you can use this:

```
ClassDate = string.IsNullOrEmpty(classDate1.Text) ? (DateTime?)null :
                DateTime.ParseExact(classDate1.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", null),
```

Comment: Now i get an error saying no implicit conversion between null and datetime

Comment: +1, but you'd get a compiler error if you did this, I believe.  Replace `null` with `(DateTime?)null`.

Comment: Hey i already did that..... since i need to insert it into the db.... Db column is datetime

Comment: @user838359: Is the database column set to be nullable or is it `NOT NULL`?

Comment: I made the field to allow nulls

Comment: @user838359: The class also must be changed to allow nulls.

Comment: Methinks the database wants to see   DBNull.Value , not C#'s   null .